# How to detect url change through AngularJS in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, angular-ui-router

I am using UIWebView which load a url of website which using AngularJS. When its load an new url (AngularJS routing) its not detecting by UIWebView delegate . How can i detect if url change in browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the current URL from `window.location.href` after the angular has been loaded, not from the `UIWebView` (`webView.request?.url?.absoluteString`).

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href")
```

> Reason: It's mainly because the URL is internally managed by the Angular router.